# Why is time not incrementing

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am trying to show the timestamp of when a process begins and when it completes, but my time never increments (even though time in reality does)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
txt1.AppendText(now + Environment.NewLine);
//Lengthy process that usually takes 2 - 3 minutes
txt1.AppendText(now);
```

Comment: Because you don't reset `now`. Think of when you set it, you are saving a copy, if you don't create another copy, the value will still be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are literally using the same variable with the same value as when you first displayed it. You would need to get the time again like this...

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
txt1.AppendText(now + Environment.NewLine);
//Lengthy process that usually takes 2 - 3 minutes
DateTime timeHasPassed = DateTime.Now;
txt1.AppendText(timeHasPassed);
```

Answer (score 3):

DateTime is a ValueType. When you assign it to a variable, you are making a copy of the value, not the reference.

This means that when you use DateTime.Now, you have to invoke it via the Get Property to get the latest time value.

```
txt1.AppendText(DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
//Lengthy process that usually takes 2 - 3 minutes
txt1.AppendText(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Unless the OP is doing something with the `now` variable (where he doesn't want it to increment between usages), this is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you captured and stored the `DateTime.Now` in a variable so it shows the stored value. Use `DateTime.Now` again instead of using now variable.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't use DateTime to measure your process time of your code.

You should never do any increment or math with `DateTime.Now` because it *may* be ambiguous due to [`DST`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and `TimeZone` issues.

Use [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure elapsed time instead. This class offers high-precision timing in .NET. It is capable of measuring time with sensitivity of around 100s of nanoseconds.

You can use it's [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Stop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to control of a `StopWatch` object.